# CiviCRM Webform Integration - User registered for event before they've made payment

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm, payment-processor

When you set up a webform in drupal for event registration in civi the last page of the form is "submit" which submits the form and registers the user and *then* takes them to the payment processor.

In the instance that someone doesn't complete the payment they are still being registered for the event.

Is there anyway to only submit the form once they've been redirected back from the payment processor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Registered for the Event but Contribution Pending Incomplete is the correct behavior in the case of an offsite payment processor.

It’s essentially a pay later (though the pay later time is shorter than mailing in a chq).

PS - on the second part of yorur question - if you use an onsite payment processor then you will have Payment fields before the Submit button

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this may be an issue with the webform integration module, not CiviCRM. If so, you'll want to post here: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform_civicrm?status=All&categories=All